# Pseudocode in latex cannot be formated

Tags: algorithms, algpseudocode

I´m writting my work and for some reasone my pseudocode in final pdf cannot be formated:

[image]

Mistake report is this:
[image]

The code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright]{report}
\let\openright=\cleardoublepage
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%%% Další užitečné balíčky (jsou součástí běžných distribucí LaTeXu)
\usepackage{amsmath}        % rozšíření pro sazbu matematiky
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % matematické fonty
\usepackage{amsthm}         % sazba vět, definic apod.
\usepackage{bm}             % tučné symboly (příkaz \bm)
\usepackage{graphicx}       % vkládání obrázků
\usepackage{fancyvrb}       % vylepšené prostředí pro strojové \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % prostředí pohodlnější nastavení hlavy a paty stránek
\usepackage{icomma}         % inteligetní čárka v matematickém módu
\usepackage{dcolumn}        % lepší zarovnání sloupců v tabulkách
\usepackage{booktabs}       % lepší vodorovné linky v tabulkách
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{
   \@ifpackagewith{xcolor}{usenames}{}{\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames}{xcolor}}
  }{\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}} % barevná sazba
\makeatother
\usepackage{multicol}       % práce s více sloupci na stránce
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\subsubsection{Vytváření clusterů}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Určení sousedících clusterů}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For {$a, b \in C$}
\State předpokládej, že $a, b$ jsou sousedící
\For {$k, l \in C$ a $k, l\neq a, b$}
\If {$P_a P_b \cap P_k P_l \neq\emptyset$}
\State $a, b$ nejsou sousedící clustery
\Else 
\If {\|$P_a P_b\|\geq \textbf{E}_r_\in_c\|P_a P_r\|$}
\State $a, b$ nejsou sousedící clustery
\EndIf
\EndIf
\EndFor
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your code still `\begin{document}` and `\end{document` is missing to be compilable :-)  I added them in the following MWE.

The culprit is the following line in your code

```
\If {\|$P_a P_b\|\geq \textbf{E}_r_\in_c\|P_a P_r\|$}
%      ^                          ^   ^
```

I changed to

```
\If {$\|P_a P_b\| \geq \textbf{E}_{r \in c} \|P_a P_r\|$}
%    ^                            ^ ^   ^ ^
```

You can not nest `_` as you did in your line and I moved the first `$` to be before `\|`.

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright]{report}

\let\openright=\cleardoublepage
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%%% Další užitečné balíčky (jsou součástí běžných distribucí LaTeXu)
\usepackage{amsmath}        % rozšíření pro sazbu matematiky
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % matematické fonty
\usepackage{amsthm}         % sazba vět, definic apod.
\usepackage{bm}             % tučné symboly (příkaz \bm)
\usepackage{graphicx}       % vkládání obrázků
\usepackage{fancyvrb}       % vylepšené prostředí pro strojové \usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % prostředí pohodlnější nastavení hlavy a paty stránek
\usepackage{icomma}         % inteligetní čárka v matematickém módu
\usepackage{dcolumn}        % lepší zarovnání sloupců v tabulkách
\usepackage{booktabs}       % lepší vodorovné linky v tabulkách
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{
   \@ifpackagewith{xcolor}{usenames}{}{\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames}{xcolor}}
  }{\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}} % barevná sazba
\makeatother
\usepackage{multicol}       % práce s více sloupci na stránce
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Vytváření clusterů}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Určení sousedících clusterů}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For {$a, b \in C$}
\State předpokládej, že $a, b$ jsou sousedící
\For {$k, l \in C$ a $k, l\neq a, b$}
\If {$P_a P_b \cap P_k P_l \neq\emptyset$}
\State $a, b$ nejsou sousedící clustery
\Else 
\If {$\|P_a P_b\| \geq \textbf{E}_{r \in c} \|P_a P_r\|$} % <===============
\State $a, b$ nejsou sousedící clustery
\EndIf
\EndIf
\EndFor
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Please correct the used mathematic to what you realy need.

Comment: Whenever I see LaTeX error output I think the team/authors behind the respective engine(s) need some competition like GCC got from Clang. After all, since Clang proved error messages (even for C++ templates) can be readable _and_ to the point GCC has improved _a lot_ in that area as well ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L If you try the OP's code, you'll see that TeX stops with `! Missing $ inserted.` and points to the line ending with `\textbf{E}_r_\in_c\|P_a P_r\|$}`, that's indeed the problem, because of the starting `\|` not in math mode.